# Acceptance or rejection of Null hypothesis

Tags: statistics

Null Hypothesis: Given two sample means are equal.
Alternative Hypothesis: Given two sample means are not equal.

It has been explained that, higher is the critical value means lower the probability of two samples belonging to same distribution. But as I get it, higher critical value implies, lower the chance of test statistic lying in the rejection region, which means null hypothesis stating that two sample means are equal, can not be rejected, i.e. there is higher probability of two samples belonging to same distribution.

Please clarify, if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Looks about right to me.

Comment: I don't understand the entire setup. How can your hypotheses be about the sample means being equal? You can just check whether they're equal. Don't you mean the means of the distributions from which they're sampled?

Comment: Well, i am pretty much a beginner in statistics. While I was looking for different kinds of statistical tests to be used, I came across this article https://towardsdatascience.com/statistical-tests-when-to-use-which-704557554740

Comment: Don Thousand, thanks for your views.I would much appreciate an explanation for your claim which would help me find, where exactly am I going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the construction of a two-sample hypothesis test of location, namely $$H_0 : \mu_1 = \mu_2 \quad \text{vs.} \quad H_a : \mu_1 \ne \mu_2,$$ where $\mu_1$ is the hypothesized mean of one group, and $\mu_2$ is the hypothesized mean of the second group.  This test is only able to conclude that the means from which the two sample are drawn are different:  it cannot conclude they are equal.  In other words, either the test rejects $H_0$ in favor of $H_a$, or the test is inconclusive and there is insufficient evidence to reject $H_0$ in favor of $H_a$.

The test statistic $T$ is a random variable that is a function of the samples and any known parameters.  Under the null hypothesis, it is a random variable with some known distribution that is independent of any unknown parameters.  Then for a significance level $\alpha$ representing the maximum Type I error allowed, we would like to find a rejection region $R$ such that $$\Pr[T \in R \mid H_0] \le \alpha;$$ that is to say, the probability that the test statistic falls in the rejection region *when the null hypothesis is true* is at most $\alpha$, meaning the probability of a Type I error (erroneous rejection of $H_0$ when $H_0$ is true) does not exceed the prespecified significance level.

Thus, for a "well-behaved" test statistic, $\alpha$ determines the "size" of $R$ and the smaller the $\alpha$, the smaller $R$ must be.  However, that doesn't imply the statement

> the higher the critical value, the lower the probability of two samples belonging to the same distribution.

The reason why the paraphrased statement is not correct is that the two samples either *are* or *are not* drawn from the same distribution.  There is no probability involved.  The frequentist paradigm is that parameters are *fixed* but unknown; they are not random variables and so it makes no sense to make a statement along the lines of $$\Pr[\mu_1 = \mu_2].$$  Another way to conceptualize this is to consider a box in which you have placed one white ball and one black ball.  I look inside the box and choose one ball to remove, and you see me take one, but I don't let you see which one I took.  Now you do not know what color ball is in the box.  You know it is either black or white, but it is definitely one color and it won't change color no matter how many times you observe it.  The same is true for your samples:  once the samples are drawn, they either are or are not from distributions with the same mean; however, the randomness is in the particular values drawn, not from the randomness of whether they were generated from distributions with the same mean.

The correct way to state the highlighted text is to say

> The higher the critical value (for a symmetric rejection region $R$ bounded by some critical value $c$, e.g. $R = \{t \in \mathbb R : |t| \ge c\}$), the lower the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis when it is true; i.e., the lower the Type I error of the test.

Note that here, we can use a probability statement, because we have assumed that the group means are equal ($H_0$ is true), but even when true, there is some nonzero probability (that in general depends on the sample size) of still realizing two samples that lead to a value of the test statistic being in the rejection region, much like how even if you flip a fair coin $10$ times, the chance you get all heads or all tails is $1/512$, simply by random chance.  Many people would be suspicious of the fairness of the coin if such a result were observed, and that is reasonable, but it isn't out of the realm of possibility.  This is the Type I error we wish to control, and it is explicitly controlled by choosing a smaller rejection region, in turn making it less likely to reject $H_0$ if $H_0$ is true.

However, in reducing the size of the rejection region, we are also increasing the burden of proof, in essence requiring that the evidence to reject $H_0$ be stronger to meet this more rigorous test.  This leads to a loss of statistical power; i.e., the failure to correctly reject $H_0$ in favor of $H_a$ when $H_a$ is true.  Your statement

> there is higher probability of two samples belonging to the same distribution

is flawed for the reasons described above.  The correct interpretation is

> when the null hypothesis cannot be rejected, the test is inconclusive:  the standard of evidence to suggest that the group means are unequal was not met.

This does not mean the group means are equal because the $p$-value of the test is conditional on $H_0$ being true; therefore, you cannot assert $H_0$ is true when you have assumed it was true in order to perform the test.  For example, if you flip a coin that is biased with $\Pr[H] = 0.5001$, it would behave almost like a perfectly fair coin, yet you know it is biased.  Flipping it only $10$ times, you may not be able to reject $H_0 : \Pr[H] = 0.5$ in favor of $H_a : \Pr[H] \ne 0.5$ even though you know $H_a$ is true!  At least how many times would you need to flip it in order to gather enough evidence such that $90\%$ of the time, you would correctly reject $H_0$?